# .htaccess if subdomain show www.site.com/subs/. no redirect url must bu sub.site.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have problem with .htaccess. 
I need:

if $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] is sub.site.com must show content from www.site.com/sub/. But URL must be  like sub.site.com.

And if sub.site.com/content/ must show content from www.site.com/sub/content/

Is it Possible?

Setting subdomains from hosting not working for me because of my CMS.

Comment: Do the both domains have same DOCUMENT_ROOT on same host or separate?

Comment: the same DOCUMENT ROOT

Comment: Now sub.site.com and www.site.com shows the same root "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^sub/)^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L,NC]
```